# What is wrong with Node.js MySQL code that just retrieves a single record

Tags: mysql, node.js

Just trying to retrieve a record from MySQL but getting an error. See article I'm using for more details. The tests are passing but I can't seem to retrieve the record.

**article credit**
https://spry-group.com/blog/Mocking-Mysql-with-Sinon/

**app.js**

```
const config = require('dotenv/config');
var mysql = require('mysql');
const UserRepository = require('./UserRepository');

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.HOST,
    user: config.USER,
    password: config.PASSWORD,
    database: config.DATABASE
});

(async () => {
    var userRepository = await new UserRepository(mysqlConnection);
    console.log(userRepository.getUserByName('Rod'));
})();
```

**UserRepository.js**

```
'use strict';
var Promise = require('bluebird');

/**
 * @constructor
 * Instantiate a user repository class.
 * @param {Object} mysqlConnection - the result of mysql.createConnection()
 */
function UserRepository(mysqlConnection) {
  this.connection = mysqlConnection;
}

/**
 * Fetch a user from the repository.
 * @param {String} username
 * @return {Promise.<UserRecord>}
 */
UserRepository.prototype.getUserByName = function(username) {
  var self = this;
  var query = 'select * from users where name = ?';
  var params = [ username ];

  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.connection
    .query(query, params, function(error, results, fields) {
       if (error) reject(new Error(error));
       console.log(results);
       resolve(results[0]);
    });
  });
  return promise;
}

module.exports = UserRepository;
```

**Output**

> PS C:\code\blog-mocking-mysql-with-sinon> npm start
>
> > Mock-Mysql-with-Sinon@0.0.1 start C:\code\blog-mocking-mysql-with-sinon
> >     node app.js
>
> Promise {   _bitField: 0,   _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
>   _rejectionHandler0: undefined,   _promise0: undefined,   _receiver0: undefined } undefined
>   C:\code\blog-mocking-mysql-with-sinon\UserRepository.js:28
>          resolve(results[0]);
>                         ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at Query._callback (C:\code\blog-mocking-mysql-with-sinon\UserRepository.js:28:23)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (C:\code\blog-mocking-mysql-with-sinon\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
>       at C:\code\blog-mocking-mysql-with-sinon\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:18
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\code\blog-mocking-mysql-with-sinon\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:397:13
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: if you type that query in database, you get record ?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can query mysql, You have to connect first. You need to connect only once, than can use that connection multiple times until you close it.

```
mysqlConnection.connect(function (error){ 
   // You may get error on DB connection here
});
...
mysqlConnection.query(...
```